# SQL Replication Security

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

I'm looking into SQL Replication for copying data from a production database to a fall back server on another domain. These two servers have completely identical database tables in terms of structure. However the data on the fall back server is a bit stale. Since this information would be passed via the internet is there some type of security with this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: My apologies. Using MS SQL Server 2014.